# Can I make an input form sortable?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I can use jQuery UI to make an ul sortable. I can do the same with a group of divs. This means that each item can move and change position.
1- It seems that it is not possible to do a form sortable, is that correct? 
2- One solution I tried is to put each form input inside a li or a div. But, is this the best way to do it?

JQUERY:

```
$(function() {
    $('#sortable').sortable();  
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li id="1">item1</li>
    <li id="2">item2</li>
    <li id="3">item3</li>
</ul>

<form id="sortable" action="extern.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="item1" name="item1" value=""  ><br>
<input type="text" id="item2" name="item2" value=""  ><br>
<input type="text" id="item3" name="item3" value=""  ><br>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you are right; it seems that it's not possible to make input fields (that have type="text") sortable. Like you said, if you use divs instead it works fine. I found one answer for this elsewhere: http://wpquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/2189

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap the `text inputs` and corresponding `labels` into `li`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/5D897/)**

HTML:

```
    <h3>Sortable form elements</h3>
<form id="" action="extern.php" method="post">
<ul id="sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default">
    Fname : <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value=""  >
</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">
    Lname : <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value=""  >
</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">
    Email : <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value=""  >
</li>    
</ul>
    </form>
```

JS code:

```
 $(function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: You can remove it ! It won't hinder sortable functionality. Please consider accepting the answer if that has really helped !

Answer (score 10):

Sortable() has an option named cancel with the default: "input, textarea, button, select, option" that prevents sorting if you start on elements matching the selector.

```
$("#sortableList").sortable({ cancel: null });
```

And you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add sorting behavior when I used TABLE, TR and TD elements within form. However, I needed to add LABEL for handling the sorting, because I wasn't able to use plain INPUT type="text" field for handling the sorting. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/wKK7E/5/)

```
$(function () {
    $('form').sortable({
        items: ".sort"
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="sortable" action="extern.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr class="sort">
            <td>
                <label>1</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="Text1" name="item1" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sort">
            <td>
                <label>2</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="Text2" name="item2" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sort">
            <td>
                <label>3</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="Text3" name="item3" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Is good to know that it can be done with a table. As I said in the question I can make a form sortable if I put each input inside a div or a li. Is there any advantage to do that with a table instead a li or a div?

Comment: I checked the differences between div and li element default display styles and it looks that it makes now difference whether you choose to use div which has block style and li that has list-item style: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_display&preval=list-item